How Raspberry Pi Pico Connect The USB Device?
I have a raspberry pi pico, a usb storage device, the usb lines with D+, D-, VCC and GUN. My develop environment is pico-sdk.

I want to connect the usb storage device to the raspberry pi pico, but I can't found the D+, D- GPIO in raspberry pi pico.
I wan to use the raspberry pi pico to read/write data from/into the usb storage device.

Which GPIO should I connect with D+ and D-?

I also have using the tinyusb library, but i can't found which GPIO should I connect.
I have found the raspberry pi pico GPIO picture in this link.


This is a hardware question, but a short answer is, for RP2040, USB_DP and USB_DM are available on pin 47 and pin 46 of the chip, it doesn't breakout to the pin connector of Pico. Pico itself is configured as a USB storage device and the PC as a host, which make no difference from a USB storage device that requires a host to interact with...

In the raspberry pi pico website, I have found it supports the host mode. The pin 47 and pin 46 are not exposed in the pico board. I want to read/write from/to the usb storage device by using pico. How can I do this?

" I have found it supports the host mode", then read the documentation or search for the example, it took me a second to find this.

I also have found this repository in github. The usb driver example has used the tinyusb library which is an open-source cross-platform USB Host/Device stack for embedded system. I also have stepped into the example codes in pico examples, but I haven't found the USB_DP and USB_DM defined in it as also the different names which contain DP or DM.
